# How to visulize image using json file in python

Tags: python, json, database, image-processing

I have an annotated JSON file as below, I want to plot annotated images with different objects in JSON file python. how can I proceed

I am trying to draw bounding boxes around images using JSON file. How can i proceed in python

```
{"objects": [{"label": "object", "position": [[0, "car", [396.5, 770.25, 43.0, 76.5]], [1, "car", [1045.5, 816.25, 34.0, 76.5]], [2, "car", [32.0, 641.0, 64.0, 35.0]], [3, "car", [286.0, 778.25, 41.0, 70.5]], [4, "car", [1091.25, 820.5, 33.5, 76.0]], [5, "car", [896.5, 63.0, 34.0, 84.0]], [6, "car", [857.75, 84.0, 31.5, 59.0]], [7, "car", [764.0, 570.25, 70.0, 39.5]], [8, "car", [323.25, 765.75, 39.5, 78.5]], [9, "car", [1100.75, 979.5, 33.5, 78.0]], [10, "car", [1052.5, 1044.0, 36.0, 72.0]], [11, "etc vehicle", [1109.0, 39.75, 45.0, 79.5]], [12, "truck", [213.0, 769.0, 89.0, 68.0]], [13, "truck", [346.75, 612.5, 80.5, 33.0]], [14, "bus", [509.25, 632.25, 169.5, 53.5]], [15, "car", [438.5, 346.0, 63.0, 32.0]], [16, "bus", [931.25, 438.25, 149.5, 147.5]], [17, "person", [1117.25, 874.25, 8.5, 12.5]], [18, "person", [1174.25, 188.75, 8.5, 13.5]], [19, "person", [682.75, 710.5, 11.5, 10.0]], [20, "person", [635.0, 509.0, 11.0, 9.0]], [21, "person", [1866.75, 195.0, 22.5, 12.0]], [22, "car", [37.75, 345.5, 75.5, 35.0]]]}], "imagePath": "img01.jpg"}
```

Comment: you have to get path from JSON, load image from this path and display it - and this depends what you use: matplotlib, pillow, cv2, some GUI framework (Tkinter, PyQt, PyGTK, etc) or some WEB framework (Flask, Django, etc.) or other module - ie. PyGame, Pyglet, etc. So problem can be broad and you didn't described details in question.

Comment: how can i display it using python? i want to display image with bounding box position value.

Comment: python has many different methods to display image - which one do you want to use? I can describe how to do it in Tkinter but next you may say that you run code in Jupyter and all my code will be useless - and this will be only waste of time. You have to declare what you use at this moment.

Comment: `from PIL import Image` `img = Image.open(data["imagePath"])` `img.show()` - is this working for you? It works on my computer.

Comment: its just orignial image, not annotated image with position value

Comment: Yes its works, but I wanted to show the image with bounding box values? how can I proceed to that?

Comment: [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) has functions [Draw.rectangle](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.rectangle) and [Draw.text](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.text) which you can use.

Comment: How it works using json file data?

Comment: it works with normal values - you have to get them JSON similar way as path - `data["imagePath"]`. And you will need `for`-loop to display all rectangles.

Comment: it does not work because we have four values in positions. that the main issue

Comment: btw: it seems you have data `[x,y,w,h]` but `Draw.rectangle` needs `[x, y, x+w, y+h]`

Comment: don't you know how to use `text = positon[1]` `box = position[2]` Or maybe you don't know that it is `[x,y,width,height]` to draw rectangle?

Comment: I know that but how i can use this for values in the position if any code you paste will be more helpfull

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem to get `x = box[0]` `y = box[1]` `w = box[2]` `h = box[3]` or even simpler `x, y, w, h = box` and later draw `rectangle([x, y, x+w, y+h], outline="red", width=1)`.

Comment: to paste code I would have to write it and there are more interesting questions which also wait for my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Python can use different modules to display images: `matplotlib`, `pillow`, `cv2`, GUI frameworks (`Tkinter`, `PyQt`, `PyGTK`, etc) or Web framework (`Flask`, `Django`, etc.) or other module - ie. `PyGame`, `Pyglet`, etc. So first you should decide what module to use. Different modules can be useful in different situations. All depends on modules which you already use and where you run code. You didn't add these details in question so I selected `pillow`.

---

This is example with [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which has [Draw.rectangle](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.rectangle) and [Draw.text](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.text)

For test I used image `lenna.png` (Wikipedia: [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna))

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

data = {
    "objects": [
        {
            "label": "object",
            "position": [
                [0, "car", [396.5, 770.25, 43.0, 76.5]],
                [1, "car", [1045.5, 816.25, 34.0, 76.5]],
                [2, "car", [32.0, 641.0, 64.0, 35.0]],
                [3, "car", [286.0, 778.25, 41.0, 70.5]],
                [4, "car", [1091.25, 820.5, 33.5, 76.0]],
                [5, "car", [896.5, 63.0, 34.0, 84.0]],
                [6, "car", [857.75, 84.0, 31.5, 59.0]],
                [7, "car", [764.0, 570.25, 70.0, 39.5]],
                [8, "car", [323.25, 765.75, 39.5, 78.5]],
                [9, "car", [1100.75, 979.5, 33.5, 78.0]],
                [10, "car", [1052.5, 1044.0, 36.0, 72.0]],
                [11, "etc vehicle", [1109.0, 39.75, 45.0, 79.5]],
                [12, "truck", [213.0, 769.0, 89.0, 68.0]],
                [13, "truck", [346.75, 612.5, 80.5, 33.0]],
                [14, "bus", [509.25, 632.25, 169.5, 53.5]],
                [15, "car", [438.5, 346.0, 63.0, 32.0]],
                [16, "bus", [931.25, 438.25, 149.5, 147.5]],
                [17, "person", [1117.25, 874.25, 8.5, 12.5]],
                [18, "person", [1174.25, 188.75, 8.5, 13.5]],
                [19, "person", [682.75, 710.5, 11.5, 10.0]],
                [20, "person", [635.0, 509.0, 11.0, 9.0]],
                [21, "person", [1866.75, 195.0, 22.5, 12.0]],            
                [22, "car", [37.75, 345.5, 75.5, 35.0]]
            ]
        }
    ],
    "imagePath": "img01.jpg"
}

data["imagePath"] = 'lenna.png'       # my image - only for tests

img = Image.open(data["imagePath"])
img = img.resize((1900, 1200))        # resize - only for tests

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

for item in data["objects"][0]["position"]:
    text = item[1]
    x, y, w, h  = item[2]
    draw.rectangle([x, y, x+w, y+h], outline='green', width=2)
    draw.text([x, y-10], text)
    
img.show()
img.save('result.jpg')
```

`lenna.png` (512x512)

[image]

`result.jpg` (1900x1200)

[image]